# optimizing an array sorting subroutine

Tags: java

I have this code below , the purpose of this program is to generate 30 random numbers in an array and sort them from ascending to descending and showing the minimum value and maximum value once sorted , i want to optimize my sortit subroutine , the method i used sorts them by checking each number and moving them depending if they are bigger or smaller than the number next to them example:
an array with these numbers : 78 19 90 8 23 
my method goes to every number and starts to  move them so lets say so far the numbers 90 and 78 are in place making the array order like this  19 8 23 78 90 , so i dont want my program to go over the numbers 23 78 and 90 since they fall into place so how can i optimize this code so it wont go over the numbers that are already in place

NB: i dont want already built functions like Array.sort()

my code:

```
public class SortProg {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int[] tab =new int[30];
        int i;
        for(i=0;i< tab.length;i++) {
            tab[i]=(int)(Math.random()*1001);
            System.out.print(tab[i]+" ");
        }

        sortIt(tab);
        System.out.print("\nThe array after sorting: \n");
        for(i=0;i< tab.length;i++) {

            System.out.print(tab[i]+" ");
        }
        System.out.print("\nThe smallest value is: "+tab[0]);
        System.out.print("\nThe biggest value is: "+tab[29]);
}
    static void sortIt(int[]tab) {
        int i,j,temp;
        for(i=0;i<tab.length-1;i++) {
            for(j=0;j<tab.length-1;j++) {
                if(tab[j]>tab[j+1]) {
                    temp=tab[j];
                    tab[j]=tab[j+1];
                    tab[j+1]=temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: yes i dont know why it didnt post it , will edit

Comment: i usually dont but it wouldnt let me copy paste it this time

Comment: okay i will do it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an unoptimized bubble sort. When the last loop is done, the last element is in position. On next loop, instead of looping to `tab.length-1` you need to loop to `tab.length-2`, then `tab.length-3` and so on.

The outer loop can be simplified. Instead of `for(i=0;i<tab.length-1;i++)`, you should do something like `while (ASwapWasMade)`, and `ASwapWasMade` is a boolean that is set to true when you're doing a swap. If no swap was made in the inner loop, it means the array is sorted and there is no need to continue sorting.

```
static void sortIt(int[]tab) {
    int j, temp;
    int length = tab.length - 1; // save it first
    boolean ASwapWasMade = true;
    while (ASwapWasMade) {
        ASwapWasMade = false; // consider by default no swap were made

        for (j = 0; j < length; j++) {
            if(tab[j] > tab[j + 1]) {
                ASwapWasMade = true; // We did a swap, set this to true, and then, the outer loop will continue
                temp=tab[j];
                tab[j]=tab[j+1];
                tab[j+1]=temp;
            }
        }
        length--; // the inner loop is done, let's decrement this because the last element is in place
    }
}
```

Comment: perfect it work great , thank you @Cid for the the help

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would suggest to read about sorting algorithms. Your code works with complexity O(n^2) and as far as I know is called [Bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). Those are the quick ones with complexity O(n*log(n)), where n is the numer of elements.

[Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)

[Merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)

[Heapsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort)

Also when you know all of it give Java built-in sorting function a try.

```
Arrays.sort(your_array_name);
```

Comment: yes i know about already built functions but i dont want to use them in this case , the simplest is array.sort but its not what i want to do in this case

Comment: Would you like to clarify what would you like to use? You want to write sorting function yourself using only loops and variables or write function using Java built-in data structures?

Comment: @samerg - The links are not to built-in functions.  They are to Wikipedia pages that describe **algorithms**.  If you want to make your code go faster, you need to understand sort algorithms.

Comment: It's not really a bubble sort. Both loops start at zero. A bubble sort is a bit more optimized and wont go through the full array every time. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort. This alone is already a huge improvment.

Comment: @StephenC oh okay ill give them a look see if i can find something that could help me out

Comment: @magicmn Bubble Sort is just an idea of sorting. There are optimized and not-optimized versions. When you start your journey with algorithms firstly you learn about not-optimized.